# Check the existence of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, template-specialization

How can I check the existence of a template function like this: Checking if `reader` struct has `read` arithmetic value

```
struct reader {
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T> read() {
        return {};
    }
};
```

I use a checker like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct test_read {
    static constexpr auto value = std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>().read<int>()),int>::value;      
};
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 static constexpr auto value = std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>().read<int>()),int>::value;
```

Please give me your advice on that.

Thank you.

---

Update: Here is the final version I got after discussion, I hope everyone will find it helpful for your code

```
struct not_reader {

};


struct reader {
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T> read() {
        return {};
    }
};


template<class T, class Elem>
struct has_read {
private:
    template<class C, typename=void>
    struct test_read : std::false_type {
    };
    template<class C>
    struct test_read<C, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<C>().template read<Elem>()), Elem>::value>::type>
            : std::true_type {
    };
public:
    using type = typename test_read<T>::type;
    static constexpr bool value = test_read<T>::value;
};


static_assert(has_read<reader, int>::value, "reader should have int read()");
static_assert(!has_read<not_reader, int>::value, "not_reader should not have int read()");
```

Comment: I edited your tags to C++14. `std::enable_if_t`  is not available in C++11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `template` before `read()`

```
static constexpr auto value
    = std::is_convertible<
         decltype(std::declval<T>().template read<int>()),int>::value;  
// .................................#########
```

But I don't think that your code can check " if `reader` struct has `read` arithmetic value": try calling `test_read` with type `int` and you should get a compilation error.

The following is an example of an alternative solution

```
#include <type_traits>

struct reader
 {
   template<typename T>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T> read()
    { return {}; }
 };

template <typename, typename = void>
struct readTypeRet
 { using type = void; };

template <typename T>
struct readTypeRet<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().template read<int>(), void())>
 { using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().template read<int>()); };

template <typename T>
struct test_read
    : public std::is_convertible<typename readTypeRet<T>::type, int>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(test_read<reader>::value == true, "!");
   static_assert(test_read<int>::value == false,   "!");
 }
```

Comment: It works, I forgot template keyword for template function like `read`. This is easier to understand :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To briefly restate your problem in terms that are a bit clearer:

- You have some function that will return `T` if `T` satisfies `is_arithmetic`, otherwise it returns `void`
- You want to assert that calling this function with `int` will return a type convertible to `int`

I think the shortest path to fix your code is to take advantage of [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) (C++11/14, use `std::invoke_result_t` in C++17):

```
template<class T>
struct test_read {
static constexpr auto value = std::is_convertible<
    typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::template read<int>)(T)>::type, int
    >::value;    
};
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gbhAUSXT9lLDXiZN)

Some notes about this solution:

- When specifying the `read` member function of `T` (`reader`), we need to use the [`template`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) keyword to inform the compiler that the name `reader` is a template.
- Use of `result_of` requires a function-like syntax of `F(Args)`, so here we are getting the type of `reader::read` as the `F` portion, and then passing `reader` as the `Args` portion

  - we must pass an instance of `T` (`reader)` to `read` because it is a member function (rather than `static` or free), and member functions implicitly take a reference to the instance of the class they're being called on.

Comment: Thank, this is more concise, however, `T` should be in place of `reader`, right?

Comment: @haint504 Whoops, yep